# JPA, Hibernate validators - email validator not applying on String

Tags: spring-data-jpa, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm trying to figure out how to validate DTO in my controller

Stack:
Spring boot 1.5.4, Spring Data JPA, Hibernate Validation 5, PostgreSQL

The problem is that I'm still getting exception about missing validators.

Any clues?

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Email' validating type 'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for 'email'
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.throwExceptionForNullValidator(ConstraintTree.java:227) ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getConstraintValidatorNoUnwrapping(ConstraintTree.java:308) ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getConstraintValidatorInstanceForAutomaticUnwrapping(ConstraintTree.java:242) ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getInitializedConstraintValidator(ConstraintTree.java:163) ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:116) ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:87) ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:73) ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:616) ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
```

DTO

```
public class CreateUserDto {

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @Email
    @NotEmpty
    private String email;

    private String password;

    private String address;

    private String phone;

    @NotNull
    private Role role;
}
```

Controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/users", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public UserDto register(@Valid @RequestBody CreateUserDto user) {
    return userService.register(user);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you are using Bean Validation 2.0 with Hibernate Validator 5.4 which only supports BV 1.1. The @Email constraint was added to the spec in 2.0 - prior to that, it was only an HV specific constraint.

You probably added a dependency to validation-api 2.0.

So:

- either you go back to BV 1.1 and you will need to use the Hibernate Validator specific @Email constraint (from the package org.hibernate.validator.constraints);
- or you upgrade HV to 6.0 (which is recommended) and you keep BV 2.0 and the javax.validation @Email constraint.

Comment: I have upgraded HV to 6.0 and it's working now, thanks

Comment: I have HV 6.0.5 and BV 2.0 and receiving the error:
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Email' validating type 'java.lang.String'.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a HV 5.x around in the classpath? If not, please try to reproduce it with our test case template (https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/master/validator) and post on our issue tracker: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/ . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a version mismatch between Bean Validation and Hibernate Validator.

You'll just need to upgrade your Hibernate validation to latest version.

#### Maven

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
   <version>6.0.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

#### Gradle

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.0.10.Final'
```